# How can I cancel submit form after password and password confirmation doesn't match

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to do a registration page for my site and I don't know how to stop users to click submit after the password and confirmation password doesn't match.

I have a function to "alert" if there is no match between the two passwords.

HTML:

```
<input type="password" name="password" value="" id="password" placeholder="Password">
<input type="password" name="confirm_password" id="confirm_password" placeholder="Confirm Password" onkeyup='check();'/>
span id='message'></span>
```

JS:

```
var check = function() {
  if (document.getElementById('password').value ==
    document.getElementById('confirm_password').value) {
    document.getElementById('message').style.color = 'green';
    document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = 'Passwords are matching';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('message').style.color = 'red';
    document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = 'Passwords does not match' ;
  }
}
```

I was thinking about boolean function, but I don't know how to call it inside of  and how to cancel the submition.

Comment: You can do it via HTML5 custom validation: https://codepen.io/diegoleme/pen/surIK (this was the result of a quick google search...). For background reading see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/setCustomValidity and more generally: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your JS, why not put the values into variables? Not necessary but will make for cleaner JS

In that function Id do something like

```
var password = document.getElementById('password').value
var confrm_password = document.getElementById('confirm_password').value


const button = document.getElementById('button') (Or however you want to target the button, up to you)
```

and than 
`button.disabled = (password === confirm_password))`

Answer (score 3):

Add a validation function to your `<form onsubmit="validate()">`

Calling `preventDefault` on the submit event will prevent the form from actually submitting.

```
function validate(event) {
  if (!passesValidation) event.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can disable the button when passwords are not matching

```
document.getElementById("Button").disabled = false;
```

Comment: I tried changing this:            <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Sign Up">
    document.getElementById('submit').disabled = false;
Still not working.

Comment: is it still clickable can you please try to change background to see the effect